# Conditional compilation error with macros

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NUM 10
main()
{     
    #ifdef NUM   
    printf("compilation succesfull");  
    #endif  
}
```

The above code compiles perfectly fine and upon execution prints
compilation successful, but if I remove a blank line before the first statement in `main()`
it gives an error. ie. "stray #" in the program and many other errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NUM 10
main()
{    #ifdef NUM                              
     printf("compilation succesfull");  
     #endif  
}
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: Parsing issue, IMHO. Heard of some rule that `#` has to be the first char of a line. Not very sure though.

Comment: You did not "remove a blank line".

Comment: @NatashaDutta first non whitespace character

Answer (score 2):

Preprocessor statements need to be on their own lines. So you can't put it on the same line as a `{` or anything else that's not part of the statement.

Answer (score 1):

The Tag `＃ifdef` you are using is correct. In the C language, lines that start with `#` in the code are called preprocessor directives. The preprocessor deletes them and uses them as commands to modify the code file prior to compilation.

For such statement for preprocessor, it should start in a new line, and only white space is allowed before the `#`. You should not put it after `{`.

For your code, compiler will like it, if it could be arranged as following.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define NUM 10
main()
{     
#ifdef NUM   
    printf("compilation succesfull");  
#endif  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor is unable to understand the line:

```
{    #ifdef NUM
```

The compiler doesn't know how to handle the statement `#ifdef NUM`, it'll say `#` is unknown and unknown type `ifdef`.

it'll reach the line

```
#endif
```

but didn't see `ifdef` before, thus you'll get `#endif without #if` error.

When you replace it in a new line, then the preprocessor knows what to do and the output will be:

```
main()
{
    printf("compilation succesfull");
}
```

Validate this by running `gcc -E yourprogram`.